# Rails 3.1 load controller from different path based on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to dynamically change the path from which controllers are used? Ryan Bates showed how to change the view_paths here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/269-template-inheritance

I'm making a CMS where a user can create a site and enter their own subdomain. I'd like "/" to point to "public#welcome" if there's no subdomain, but if there is a subdomain, I want it to point to "sites/public#welcome".

I'm using Rails 3.1 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
  constraints(:subdomain => /.+/) do
    scope :module => "sites" do
      root :to => 'public#welcome'
    end
  end

  root :to => 'public#welcome'
```

Now when a user visits "/" Sites::PublicController will be used if a subdomain exists, but just PublicController if no subdomain exits. Adding `scope :module => "sites" do...end` keeps my routes file simplistic and manageable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this situation using constraints if I'm not mistaken (which I might, since I haven't actually tried the following yet):

```
constraints(:subdomain => /.+/) do
  root :to => 'sites/public#welcome'
end

root :to => 'public#welcome'
```

Comment: How would I add a resource... say a Post resource? Where there would be crud operations at both /posts and /sites/posts ??

Comment: And they would be using different controllers?