# Rails 3.1 Subdomain-specific Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a setup where I have an engine (non-namespaced) [for each subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322496/rails-3-1-custom-controllers-and-views-w-default).  This works great because each subdomain is able to specify their own custom routes, controllers, views, and models.  But I haven't been able to figure out how to get assets to do what I want them to.  Ideally javascript and stylesheets are only loaded for a particular subdomain if that subdomain is visited.  I don't want one stylesheet definition overwriting another in a different community.

Furthermore, I'd like images to be accessible as normal when using `image_tag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out a solution.  The JS, CSS, and images should all be stored in the default location of the engine, e.g. `app/assets/javascripts/<subdomain>/application.js`.  Then, in the main app's `application.html.erb` JS and CSS should be included like so:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "#{community.subdomain}/application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "#{community.subdomain}/application" %>
```

As for images, as long as they're in `app/assets/images/<subdomain>/` of the engine, they'll show up in public as `/assets/images/<subdomain>/my_image.png`.  Again, I'm using Rails 3.1; I'm not sure how this behavior is for other versions of Rails, including 3.0.

Comment: Just came across this and works excellent in th elatest 3.2.11 release. Thanks!